# MAUI ItemsControl+DataTemplates (like WPF)?

Tags: coordinates, maui, datatemplate

I'd like to create a diagram (objects in canvas with X and Y coordinates) and define the view using DataTemplate like I would do with WPF in an ItemsControl.

Using classic :

- MV classes : class A, class B, class C
- Templates : DataTemplate x:Type A, DataTemplate x:Type B, DataTemplate x:Type C
- "ItemsControl" Binding AllClasses.

It seems it's not possible in XAML with MAUI.

Which would be the prettiest way (Full xaml or less code possible) to do it, please ?
Nitro